# static method in multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, static, java-threads

I have a static method

```
public static void abc(String str) {
    // some code
    str = str + "s";
    // some code
}
```

Lets assume that this method is called by 100 threads at the same time.

I think that CPU schedules all these threads to execute this static method.

Lets scale up execute requests. Now, there are around 100000 threads calling this static method around same time.

If it is so, this will be a performance overhead (compared to the case where this method is a member of a class). Am I correct?

Comment: The cost of context switching the threads will far exceed any difference due to static vs non-static.

Comment: I have no idea what you might even be implying. The performance hit of _what_ exactly? How is it different to call an instance method vs. static method?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik There is only one instance of the static method of a class  in memory. If all threads are invoking this static method around same time, there might be waiting time for remaining threads.

Comment: Ok, then your question comes from basic misunderstanding. There's only one instance of _any_ method and any number of threads may execute it at any time. Only locks cause mutual exclusion.

Answer (score 5):

- In theory, a static call can be made slightly more efficient because it doesn't need to do a virtual function lookup, and it can also avoid the overhead of the hidden "this" parameter.
- In practice, many compilers will optimize this out anyway.
- The cost of context switching the threads will far exceed any difference due to static vs non-static method calling

Answer (score 4):

From the perspective of the OS's scheduler it doesn't matter whether the method is static or not. At machine level both are just subroutines with some parameters. So unless neither methods are synchronized, there shouldn't be any difference.